# Add New Image Attribute in Magento backend and Get all images of that new image attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have added the new image attribute in magento admin by creating new attribute using catalog=>attributes=>manage attribute and new attribute is showing in admin.

but problem is that how I can get all images of this attribute.?[image]

I added the Pos image attribute .Now I want all images of this attribute using coding.Please help

Comment: get all image for this attribute ?means for specific product ?

Comment: yes I want to get the image of a specific product .I want to get baseimage,smallimage,thumbnail,posimage.

Comment: yes thanks for help dude.new image attribute image comes in product data.that solved my problem .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?$_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();?>
    <?if($_images){?>           
       <?$i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++;?>
          <a href="#"><img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(200, 130); ?>" width="200" height="130" alt="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /></a>              
           <a href="#"><img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $_image->getFile())->resize(200, 130); ?>" width="200" height="130" alt="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /></a>               
       <?}?>
    <?}?>
```

you can get image using this code change your label to get different image if thumbnail then use thumbnail

Comment: Can We check whether image attribute type is thumbnail,image,pos image using coding for a particular product

Comment: ya you can check in $_product object just write $_product->getData() and you can get all information about particular product

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a theme og magento.from where I have to start. I know the basic struture of magento.Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have different question then ask question separately